# using exec() with python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

so normally if i run these  script with this code:

```
x=5
exec("x+=1")
output=str(x)
```

If I execute the above in a python console, output has a value of "6"
But if it's run inside a function, the exec doesn't change the value of x.

Why does this happen, and how could I get the same behavior in a function as i do in the console?

Comment: What does "inside a wsgi app" mean in this context? I have a nagging doubt that you aren't running the exact same code in both cases.

Comment: added a sample wsgi app to be crystal clear

Comment: as Lennart clarified, this issue had nothing to do with wsgi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WSGI has nothing to do with it. Your test that works is not running the same or even similar code. Here is your WSGI code made into non-WSGI:

```
>>> def app():
...     x=5
...     exec("x+=1")
...     print(x)
... 
>>> app()
5
```

As you see, it also doesn't change `x`. The code that did was this:

```
>>> x=5
>>> exec("x+=1")
>>> print(x)
6
```

The difference is that in one case it's global, in the other case local. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#exec): "modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be attempted."

You can change a global by doing this:

```
x=5
def app():
    exec("global x;x+=1")
    print(x)

app()
```

And you can change a local by doing it explicitly:

```
def app():
    x=5
    d = {'x': x}
    exec("x+=1", d)
    x = d['x']
    print(x)

app()
```

If you have many locals you need access to, you can use `d=locals().copy()`.

Comment: It may be worth explicitly noting that in the 2.x series, where `exec` is a statement in its own right rather than an ordinary builtin function, it actually *does* support implicit modifications to the local namespace inside a function. It's a bad idea though, since it forces the compiler to switch off the optimised local variable access feature inside that particular function. Regardless of the wisdom of doing it in the first place, code that uses tricks like this may fail if ported from Python 2 to Python 3.